# Почему элемент Arraylist передается в метод в качестве параметра, если явно это не указано?

Tags: java, arraylist

Не знаю можно ли тут публиковать такое, но я недавно начал изучение программирования и встретил вот такой код. Никак не могу понять - почему он работает:)Вызова метода paySalary нигде нет. В него не передаются никакие данные. Он только принимает в качестве входящих данных String name. Нигде явно не указано, что String name это элементы ArrayList и тем не менее программа работает...

```
package com.javarush.task.pro.task12.task1209;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static ArrayList<String> waitingEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> alreadyGotSalaryEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void initEmployees() {
        waitingEmployees.add("Гвинно");
        waitingEmployees.add("Гунигерд");
        waitingEmployees.add("Боргелейф");
        waitingEmployees.add("Нифрод");
        waitingEmployees.add("Альбиуф");
        waitingEmployees.add("Иногрим");
        waitingEmployees.add("Фриле");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initEmployees();
    }

    public static void paySalary(String name) {
        if (waitingEmployees.contains(name) && !alreadyGotSalaryEmployees.contains(name)) {
            alreadyGotSalaryEmployees.add(name);
            for (int i = 0; i < waitingEmployees.size(); i++) {
                if (waitingEmployees.get(i).equals(name)) {
                    waitingEmployees.set(i, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему программа не должна работать?

Comment: Я написал почему, как мне кажется, не должен) И вопрос собственно не в том почему не работает, а в том - как работает этот механизм - неявная передача информации от ArrayList в метод, если явно нигде элементы не передаются.

Comment: почему нигде не указано? if (waitingEmployees.contains(name)... если в массиве waitng найдется элемент, который равен name то...

Comment: во-первых метод нигде не вызывается.  поэтому работать должно независимо от того, что написано в методе..... а почему arrayList должен явно передаваться, если он является свойством класса и доступ к нему из любого метода есть

Comment: Вы имеете в виду каким образом метод paySalary получает доступ к листам waitingEmployees и alreadyGotSalaryEmployees? Если да, то он имеет к ним доступ, так как это поля его же класса, при этом и поля и сам метод статические. Если бы поля были нестатитеческие, то он бы не имел к ним доступа.

Comment: в принципе я так и думал...но меня сбило с толку - зачем тогда в метод передается String name?

Comment: а как с чем вы будете сравнивать, если ничего не передавать?

Comment: Простите...я неправильно задал вопрос...я имел в виду откуда name берет значения? Ну то есть метод нигде не вызывается и данные в него соответственно не передаются. Записи типа "name = ..." тоже нигде нет. В метод приходит какая-то переменная, которая откуда-то знает что в ней должны храниться значения из ArrayList.

Comment: namе берёт значение из аргумента, переданного в вызываемый метод. Но на данный момент он не вызывается. если написать в main например `paySalary("Фриле");`  то и начнётся работа этого метода

Comment: переменная name не является типом ArrayList. Это переменная со строковым типом. Метод оперирует листами, которые являются свойствами класса.

Comment: Я в принципе именно об этом и писал в начале...дело в том, что если бы метод вызывался в main и  в него передавалось значение, как вы и указали в примере, то у меня бы вообще не было вопросов. Но метод работает без вызова. И в name каким-то образом попадают все значения из списка по порядку. Хотя это просто переменная - не массив, и нигде нет цикла, в который бы по порядку заносились значения в name.

Comment: Почему ты решил, что метод работает без вызова?